# Objects aren´t filled

Tags: java, object, return

I´m trying to fill an object Pos
Pos class:

```
private int degree, minute, tenth;
private Pos pos;
private int d;
private int m;
private int t;

public Pos(int d, int m, int t){
    this.d = degree;
    this.m = minute;
    this.t = tenth;

}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return (this.degree + " " + this.minute + "." + this.tenth);
}
```

this is the class where i print the objects(it's quite a lot but i had it to check the layout:

```
 In in;
    String fileName = "charts.txt";
    int aantalKaarten;
    int kolommen;
    String[][] tabel;
    int n1,n2,n3,s1,s2,s3,w1,w2,w3,e1,e2,e3;
    String color;
    String edition;
    String scale;
    String title;

    in = new In(fileName);
    aantalKaarten = in.readInt()+1;
    for(int i = 0, kaart = 0;i < aantalKaarten;i++, kaart++){
        try {
            n1 = in.readInt();
            n2 = in.readInt();
            n3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Noordelijke lengtegraad: " + n1 + ", " + n2 + ", " + n3);
            s1 = in.readInt();
            s2 = in.readInt();
            s3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Zuidelijke lengtegraad: " + s1 + ", " + s2 + ", " + s3);
            w1 = in.readInt();
            w2 = in.readInt();
            w3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("westelijke breedtegraad: " + w1 + ", " + w2 + ", " + w3);
            e1 = in.readInt();
            e2 = in.readInt();
            e3 = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("oostelijke breedtegraad: " + e1 + ", " + e2 + ", " + e3);
            color = in.readString();
            System.out.println("De kleur van de kaart: " + color);
            edition = in.readString();
            System.out.println("Editie: " + edition);
            scale = in.readString();
            System.out.println("Schaal: " + scale);
            title = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Kaart: " + title);
            System.out.println("");
            Pos north = new Pos(n1,n2,3);
            Pos south = new Pos(s1,s2,s3);
            Pos west = new Pos(w1,w2,w3);
            Pos east = new Pos(e1,e2,e3);
            Chart[] kaartenArray = new Chart[aantalKaarten];
            Chart charts = new Chart(north, south, west, east, color, scale, edition, title);
            kaartenArray[kaart] = charts;
            String string1;
            string1 = kaartenArray[kaart].toString();
            System.out.println("string1: " +string1);
            System.out.println(kaart);
            System.out.println("");

        }
        /*catch(NoSuchElementException eNSEE){
            System.out.println("No such element exception: " + eNSEE);
        }*/
        catch(StackOverflowError eSOE){
            System.out.println("StackOverflowError: " + eSOE);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException eNPE){
            System.out.println("NullpointerException" + eNPE);
        }

    }
    in.close();


}
```

}

Here's the constructor from class chart:

```
 private String title;//Titel van de kaart.
private String colorString;//kleur waarin het kader van de kaart moet worden getekend door de klasse
                           //DrawCartotheek (B,G) voor respectievelijk blauw of groen
private String scale;//Schaal van de kaart: Bij voorbeeld: 1:50000
private String edition;///Het jaar van uitgifte van de kaart. Bij voorbeeld: ed:2011/2012
private Pos north;//De noordelijkste breedtegraad van de kaart
private Pos south;//De zuidelijkste breedtegraad van de kaart
private Pos west;//De westelijkste lengtegraad van de kaart
private Pos east;//De oostelijkste lengtegraad van de kaart

private Chart Chart;

public Chart(Pos north, Pos south, Pos west, Pos east, String color, String scale, String edition, String title){
    //Constructor. Maakt een object van het type Chart wijst de parameters
    //toe aan de respectievelijke attributen.
    this.north = north;
    this.south = south;
    this.west = west;
    this.east = east;
    this.colorString = color;
    this.scale = scale;
    this.edition = edition;
    this.title = title;
}
```

this is the text file that i'm processing:

```
 20
 51 53 00 3 49 00 51 49 70 3 59 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 5
 51 53 00 3 59 00 51 49 70 4 09 15 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 6
 51 49 50 3 28 90 51 42 10 3 49 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 7-8
 51 49 50 3 49 00 51 42 10 4 09 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 9-10
 51 41 80 3 19 20 51 34 00 3 39 60 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 11-12
 51 42 20 3 39 40 51 34 40 3 59 70 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 13-14
 51 42 40 3 59 70 51 34 60 4 19 80 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 15-16
 51 42 60 4 19 60 51 34 80 4 29 80 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 17
 51 34 20 3 19 80 51 26 80 3 39 90 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 19-20
 51 34 60 3 39 80 51 26 80 4 00 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 21-22
 51 34 60 3 59 70 51 27 20 4 20 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 23-24
 51 26 70 3 20 00 51 19 00 3 40 20 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 25-26
 51 27 00 3 40 00 51 19 40 4 00 00 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 27-28
 51 27 15 4 00 00 51 19 60 4 20 20 B ed:2011/2012 1:50.000 ANWB Z 29-30
 51 27 60 2 28 60 51 00 00 2 58 40 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.2
 51 32 00 2 51 60 51 13 70 3 36 00 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.3
 51 30 50 3 22 50 51 20 50 3 44 30 G ed:2012      1:50.000  Hydro 1801.4
 51 48 60 3 00 00 51 30 40 3 40 00 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.5
 52 00 06 3 23 00 51 42 40 4 07 20 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.6
 52 15 60 3 46 40 51 57 60 4 29 60 G ed:2012      1:100.000 Hydro 1801.7
```

Here is the outcome of the code when i run te class(only the first two because it's otherwise so long:

```
 run:
 Noordelijke lengtegraad: 51, 53, 0
 Zuidelijke lengtegraad: 3, 49, 0
 westelijke breedtegraad: 51, 49, 70
 oostelijke breedtegraad: 3, 59, 0
 De kleur van de kaart: B
 Editie: ed:2011/2012
 Schaal: 1:50.000
 Kaart:  ANWB Z 5

 Chart:  ANWB Z 5, ed:2011/2012, 1:50.000 north: 0 0.0 south: 0 0.0 west: 0 0.0 east: 0 0.0

 Noordelijke lengtegraad: 51, 53, 0
 Zuidelijke lengtegraad: 3, 59, 0
 westelijke breedtegraad: 51, 49, 70
 oostelijke breedtegraad: 4, 9, 15
 De kleur van de kaart: B
 Editie: ed:2011/2012
 Schaal: 1:50.000
 Kaart:  ANWB Z 6

 Chart:  ANWB Z 6, ed:2011/2012, 1:50.000 north: 0 0.0 south: 0 0.0 west: 0 0.0 east: 0 0.0
```

As you can see the result of the pos objects are all 0. It outputs this format: degree minute.tenth as you can see in the Pos class. Where for example north should be 51 53.0 and so on.

Really hope someone can help me find what i'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly then:

```
public Pos(int d, int m, int t){
    this.d = degree;
    this.m = minute;
    this.t = tenth;
}
```

Should be:

```
public Pos(int d, int m, int t){
    this.d = d;
    this.m = m;
    this.t = t;
}
```

And toString should be:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return (this.d + " " + this.m + "." + this.t);
}
```

Comment: That's right. And the `toString()` should be:

`public String toString(){
    return (this.d+ " " + this.m+ "." + this.t);
}`

Comment: Thanks, added the mention to answer.

Comment: After these two changes it finally worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Additionally you can remove the lines private int degree, minute, tenth;
private Pos pos;